# Java: Detect when user clicks outside the window boundries

Tags: java, click, mouse, screen-capture

I am working on design for a screen video capture program in Java I already have what it takes to create the screenshots and save them with [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250050/java-capture-video-of-whats-on-the-screen). Now as an added bonus I would like to know when the user clicks so I can add a visual indicator that makes it clear where the user clicked and that it was not just a mouseover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really possible in Java, which makes sense: OS routes the mouse event only once, and to the window that's supposed to receive it, so why should you be able to grab it? You could however write some system-level code on the level of OS handling of mouse events...

check this out: [Detecting a Mouse Click Anywhere on Screen with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869294/detecting-a-mouse-click-anywhere-on-screen-with-java)