# Making a video using java code or an open source tool?

Tags: java, video-streaming, video-capture

I have a script that executes a test case by opening a specific website, let me illustrate this by the following example -:

1. My script opens up the web page www.google.com
2. Enters some text in the search box
3. Presses the button search
4. Then clicks the first link on the search page.

The problem is that I need to make a real time screencast of this whole process i.e all the actions need to be captured, here I am not talking about the screenshots, I need this process to be integrated in my project, can anyone suggest me some tools or point me to any java library that does the trick for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible dups:
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250050/java-capture-video-of-whats-on-the-screen
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464593/how-to-capture-selected-screen-of-other-application-using-java

Comment: I don't know what led you to make a negative vote, I think its a perfectly right question, you should first review whats written in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use freeware [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) - tool for recording all screen and audio activity on your computer. You can record video in *Streaming Flash* format or make the AVI file.

Comment: can we integrate it with the java code such that whenever a script executes a new thread is instantiated that activates camstudion and makes a new video of the process everytime